# eWay payment Gateway Recurring payment

Tags: payment-gateway, payment

How to check Current Transaction made by eway and how to update my expire date and time if payment success.

Is there any function to check recent transaction made by eway.

```
 $requestbody = array(
            'RebillCustomerID' => $rebillCustomerID,
            'RebillID' => $rebillID
        );
        $client = $this->createObjet();
        return $result = $client->QueryTransactions($requestbody);
```

I use this, but at return all transaction details .
Please help me if there is any other option to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an API to return only the most recent transaction with eWAY's recurring. You can find the current transaction by looking for the most recent transaction time for any transaction which isn't "Pending" or "Future".

A quick example of doing so would go as follows:

```
$requestbody = array(
    'RebillCustomerID' => $rebillCustomerID,
    'RebillID' => $rebillID
);

$result = $client->QueryTransactions($requestbody);

$current = mostRecent($result);

function mostRecent ($result){
    $return = '';
    foreach ($result->QueryTransactionsResult->rebillTransaction as $r) {
        $mostRecent = 0;
        if ($r->Status != 'Pending' && $r->Status != 'Future') {
            $curDate = strtotime($r->TransactionDate);
            if ($curDate > $mostRecent) {
                $mostRecent = $curDate;
                $return = $r;
            }
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```